# Finding a power series for $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

Tags: derivatives, power-series

I'm trying to find a power series representation of: $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

I know the following:
$$\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n$$

My understanding is that if I differentiate the left and right sides of the equation, I'll get (close to) my answer.

Left side:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}$$

Right side:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nnx^{n-1}$$

Since the left side has a $-1$ on top and the original equation doesn't, my understanding is that I need to multiply the right side (the summation) by $-1$ to compensate:

$$-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nnx^{n-1}$$

When I check the answer to the original equation in my text (and Wolfram Alpha), it gives the power series as:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n+1)x^{n}$$

Can anyone help me understand where I've gone astray?

Comment: What are the first few terms of your series, and of Wolfie's series?

Comment: In the sum before the last, it starts by $n=1$   or you replace $n $ by $n+1$ and it will start from $n=0$.

Comment: You got the right answer, just written in a slightly different way. I also think you've done something like $\frac{d}{dx}1=\frac{d}{dx}x^0=0\cdot x^{-1}$ which is kind-of correct (except for $x=0$) but would look much better if you omitted the term $n=0$ altogether.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I see now that the indices are different. How do I know when I need to change the index of a sum after differentiation?

Comment: @AlexJohnson You don't need to change indices, your solution is not incorrect because your indices are off by one. For another example, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$ is the same as the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}$. You may prefer one or the other for purely aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* There is no reason to compensate for   anything.

> The RHS is
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nnx^{n-1}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nnx^{n-1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)x^{n}
> \end{align*}
>   Equating LHS and RHS gives
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\color{blue}{-1}}{(1+x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n\color{blue}{+1}}(n+1)x^{n}
> \end{align*}
>   and finally
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)x^n
> \end{align*}
>   as it should be.

Comment: On the first line you changed indices from $n = 0$ to $n = 1$ but changed nothing else. Was that an error or did I miss something else?

Comment: @AlexJohnson: The summand with factor $n=0$ is zero.

Comment: In other words, since the term when $n = 0$ is zero, we can ignore it and start our summation at $n = 1$, correct?

Comment: @AlexJohnson: Correct. That's precisely what's going on.

Comment: Looking back through this, I realize that your final sum is negative, while the answer I have in my text and in Wolfram is positive. Am I missing something here, too?

Comment: @AlexJohnson: Multiplication of *both* sides with $-1$ gives the wanted representation. The point is that this time this is no (one sided) compensation, but an admissible equivalence transformation on both sides.